# How to get a picture from phonegap to a remote XPage?

Tags: cordova, xpages

I've built an Phonegap App with version 1.6 on my iPad
an set the ulr to an XPage on the Domino Server

now to my problem:

When I take a picture on the iPhone and upload it to my XPage
using the function `takePicture` the "returnvalue" is a String like this

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/C1ABCAD3-5F54-45AB-81B0-A242940B58CB/tmp/photo_001.jpg
```

is there a chance to get the file uploaded and not the string?

here is the code I'm using:

```
XSP.submitLatency = 300*1000;

function takePicture() {    
    navigator.camera.getPicture(displayPicture,
     showError,
      { quality: 50 }

      ); 

}

function displayPicture(data) {

alert("Hallo" );
    var imagePanel = document.getElementById('imagePanel');
    imagePanel.style.display = "";
    imagePanel.style.position = "absolute";
    imagePanel.style.top = "250px";
    imagePanel.style.left = "0px";




    alert("data:image/jpeg;base64," + data)
    document.getElementById('image').src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
    document.getElementById("#{javascript:getClientId('inputHidden1')}").value = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;

    document.getElementById("#{javascript:getClientId('button1')}").disabled = false;
}

function showError(fail) {
    alert(fail);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to ask the [getPicture](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture) method to return a FILE_URI instead of the DATA_URL by specifying the destinationType as part of the [options](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions_options). Once you have the URI you can use [FileTransfer.upload](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_upload) to upload your file.

Comment: Ah thanks but ive readed that with destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL it should return a Base64-encoded image not the Filepath.

Comment: I think you ran into a bug in 1.6.0 which should be fixed in 1.6.1. You are on iOS right?

Comment: Args ok I used the 1.6 not the 1.6.1. Yes im on iOS